# Where would I place an HTML file to be viewed with web view

Tags: android, html, web

Being very new to android development I am asking for some help with a problem I have.  I need to view an HTML file through a Web View on mobile devices.  The HTML file, 3 in total, would be saved on the device.  My question is where would I put these files and how would I call them.  I know that it can be done on an iPhone as I have done it, but as I know next to nothing about Android and I am in need of guidance. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the purpose of the html file?

Comment: @JRsz the purpose of the html files is quite simple, they are 3 text files which form the bulk of my app and have to remain in html format due to the links contained in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your HTML in the assets folder and just:

```
WebView view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.your_web_view);  
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_file_name.html");
```

If you don't have an assets folder, just create it:

> Right click on your app -> New -> Folder -> Assets Folder

Comment: many thanks for your help, from your "stats" it is unlikely but perhaps one day down the road I can help you

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: ..Please excuse me but in the above code you say "android_asset" what are you referring to and is the html extension needed or must it be dropped? Sorry to be a pain but as I say I am very new to this and as such many questions